# Lock a function from another function in java

Tags: java, locking

I need lock a function from another function in java. In example above, I call slave function to print counter. And I need when that if master function called, all threads which calls slave function must be wait master functions to be ended.

How can I do that?

```
int counter = 0;

private void slave()
{
  System.out.println(counter);
}

private void master()
{
  lockSlave();
  counter ++;
  unlockSlave();
}
```

Comment: You really don't need any locks for this particular task. Consider using [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or [`LongAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html)

Comment: It's just an example you know. In real slave function in my repository includes a lot of complex algorithms, not basic counter. @SashaSalauyou

Comment: Yes I understand. Just tried to put your attention to another JDK components that are extremely useful in concurrency programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at JDK [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

```
private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

private void slave()
{
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        System.out.println(counter);
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

private void master()
{
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        counter ++;
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: if counter is thread-safe, no lock is needed. If the lock is acquired for every `counter++`, it doesn't need to be thread-save nor volatile

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. Also make your variable volatile so changes can be seen by all threads.

```
ReadWriteLock m_lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
Lock m_readLock = m_lock.readLock();
Lock m_writeLock = m_lock.writeLock();

volatile int counter = 0;

private void slave() {
  m_readLock.lock();
  try {
    System.out.println(counter);
  } finally {
    m_readLock.unlock();
  }
}

private void master(){
  m_writeLock.lock();
  try {
    counter ++;
  } finally {
    m_writeLock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Comment: the common idiom is to acquire a lock before `try`, not inside it, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html As `.lock()` itself may throw, after which you'll get an exception in `finally`

Answer (score -1):

Use synchronized word, is what is for, you can synchronize the full method, so only one thread will be able to run at once.

Comment: That's true. But but synchronized only "locks" one method, the question is about two different methods.